#  Is there a way to hack a Mac Book Pro to allow higher monitor resolution?

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

Is there a way to hack a Mac Book Pro to allow higher monitor resolution? Currently 1220x800, and its way too low.

(Doubt it's possible)

Comment: Yeah, no. LCD monitors don't work like that, and trying to run them higher runs a serious risk of damaging them, and no chance of working.

Comment: How about an external monitor?

Answer (score 1):

I have a MacBook that has comparable resolution to yours - perhaps the same, but I use an external LCD monitor when I am at home.  It connects with a mini-DVI to HDMI adapter and an HDMI cable.  With this, I use 1680x1050 resolution and this is very good for most programming, browsing, etc.  The MacBook supports external only or external + internal displays.

Out of my home office, I am stuck with a small screen and low resolution - just like you.